# Ignore Hibernate @Where annotation

Tags: hibernate, annotations, where-clause

I have an Entity which has an association to another Entity annotated with @Where, like so

```
public class EntityA {

    @OneToMany
    @Where(...)
    private List<EntityB> entityBList;

}
```

Recently the inevitable has happened, I need to load EntityB's that don't conform to the @Where clause. I could remove the @Where annotation, but it is used a lot, so ideally I don't want to do that. Apart from loading the list of EntityB's manually, with another query, what are my options? Can I tell Hibernate to ignore the @Where annotation?

Comment: I don't get it: do you need the `@Where` or not ?

Comment: I need it for 99% of the queries, but there is one for which I do not need it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After lots of research it appears that this is simply impossible. I'd strongly suggest avoiding @Where, as it is hard to predict beforehand if you'll ever need those associations or not.

Comment: please delete this comment, as it is false.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659984/hibernate-how-to-ignore-where-annotation#24660159

Answer (score 26):

I just had the same question. I solved the problem like this:

```
@Query(value="SELECT * FROM EntityA", nativeQuery=true)
public ignoreWhereMethod(){}
```

The SQL in the @Query annotation must point the table's name and the fields' names (not entity's name).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it doesn't force to delete the annotation on entity and works perfectly fine.

Comment: This worked for me as well, This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

I know its an old question but in case anyone look for an answer...
I had the same dilemma, you don't want to mess your code with "is_deleted= false" every where you select,

simple solution is to use native SQL:

```
lst = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
createSQLQuery("select {entb.*}  from EntityB entb where  is_deleted=1")                            
           .addEntity("entb", EntityB.class)
           .list();
```

Comment: Do you know if it is the same solution when someone uses @Query annotation and JPQL?

Comment: It is the same, see solution from @yuri-hassle-araújo

Answer (score 6):

You can map another property with same data like this:

```
public class EntityA {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name='theColumnName', insertable=false, updateable=false)
    private List<EntityB> entityBListReadOnly;

}
```

Important to set as updateable false and insertable falso to avoid consistency problems in your data!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is filter, as explained in this question.
[Hibernate how to ignore @Where annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659984/hibernate-how-to-ignore-where-annotation#24660159)

I will be trying this myself because the combination of `@where` and `@NamedNativeQueries` is a very cumbersome solution in our situation. But I do not know yet if `@Filter` is any better.

Comment: this question is from 2010 please seek modern solutions

Comment: I would love to find modern solutions but alas I am not capable. Finally I had to step down to the `@where` and `@NamedNativeQueries` solutions mentioned by myself. But you are perfectly right that this is not ideal. I am open to proposals :-)