# overwrite @Where JPA annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem with an appointment. A persistence is controlled with JPA and there is an annotation @where an entity that "fails" a value of 0 for that column anywhere it is made in that entity. If you are selecting an ID for example, hibernate will automatically be inserted where the column specified in @where is 0.

The problem is that now I have a where in that column where = 1 and hibertant overrides my where and bring only records with a value of 0.

My question is there any kind of ignoring this where only in my consultation? you will enter the code below.

Thank you!

```
SELECT blah blah blah
```

Here inner join with the table I have to do the inner join

```
inner join
        minhatabela mtabela 
            on outratabela.id=mtabela.id_outratabela 
            and (
                mtabela.coluna = 0 // This where automatically enters whenever this table is used due to the @where annotation in the entity
            )

from
    outratabela
        where

outratabela.id=66666666 
        and minhatabela.coluna=1
```

My Entity

```
> @Entity @Table(name = "minhatabela") @Data @Builder @NoArgsConstructor
> @AllArgsConstructor @Where(clause = "coluna = 0") 
// This annotation
> overwrites, but I can't remove it because it is used in every system and
> I would have to touch several points. public class MinhaTabela {
> 
> ...........
```

Is there any way to ignore this annotation only in my criteria?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a similar answer.[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659984/hibernate-how-to-ignore-where-annotation). One solution is to used native query instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore Hibernate @Where annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311125/ignore-hibernate-where-annotation)

Comment: Thanks friends, I had to do the native query